# Output redirection while starting the app in linux

Tags: linux, redirect

If i redirect logging while starting some application to the other file like this:

```
./someapp.sh > somefile.log
```

how to fix this line to be able to see the output not only in this file but also in the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tool called [`tee(1)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/tee/) for the job.

```
./someapp.sh | tee somefile.log
```

Answer (score 0):

```
./someapp.sh 2>&1 | tee somefile.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command in another terminal:
`tail -f somefile.log`.
This will print everything written on the console immediately.